# Multiple Attachment fields on an Infopath form

Tags: infopath, attachments

I'm setting up a Infopath form which has a number of different views. On each view I need to ability to add a different attachment to each view, but every time I put the field in a view it duplicates the first Attachment Field. How do I make the Attachment Field unique to the view?

Answer (score 0):

The attachments field in the underlying SharePoint list does not work like that. You would need metadata to go along with it, and the attachments field does not have that included.

You can probably achieve your goals if you create an associated document library. I would write the InfoPath form as a web-enabled form, and then add a web part for the doc library below the InfoPath form (not in it, because the tools from InfoPath are clumsy for this. Then you only need to manage the web filters passed to the web part, then make sure your document library requires the data you are filtering on.

Comment: Cheers. What I think I'll do is set up a separate Document library so that a user can upload a document and then link it to the form using a  Hyperlink control